# Extract HTML information from df variable

Tags: html, pandas, kml

Dear stackoverflow community,

This is my first time asking a question here. Hope you could cut me some slack.
Here is the description of a problem:

1. I convert KML file to CSV using ogr2org 
   `ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv 'some KML file'.kml`
2. I then read in the csv file in pandas 
   `data = pd.read_csv('output.csv')`

3. After deleting some bizarre columns I end up having the following:

```
In[1]: data.head(8)
Out[1]: 
                                          description   ID
0   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   1
1   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   10
2   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   100
3   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   1000
4   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   10000
5   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   10001
6   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   10002
7   <div class="googft-info-window">\n<b>ID:</b> 1...   10003
```

4. The representative string under **description** variable is as follows:

```
    <div class=""googft-info-window"">
    <b>ID:</b> 1<br>
    <b>class:</b> 1<br>
    <b>fold:</b> 5
    </div>
```

My question is how can I extract clean information from the 'description' column and add it to the same row using all the `<b>...<\b>` as a column names.

Thank you.
P.S. Please let me know how I can improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.extractall` with...

```
df[['ID1', 'class', 'fold']] = df['description'].str.extractall(r'</b>\s?(\d+)<').unstack()
```

Or `str.findall` with something like this...

```
df[['ID1', 'class', 'fold']] = df['description'].str.findall(r'</b>\s?(\w+)<', expand=True)
```

These are based on a string like...

```
<div class=""googft-info-window""><b>ID:</b> 1<br><b>class:</b> 1<br><b>fold:</b> 5</div>
```

With the regex matching the three values you need from the string being extracted and passed to the three new columns on the left of the `=` sign.

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/wVl2cI/1

This is assuming you only have three values to find and the HTML is all the same.

**Outputs (example):**

```
    description             ID1    class    fold
0   <div class=""googft-..  1      1        1
1   <div class=""googft-..  1      1        1
2   <div class=""googft-..  5      5        5
```