# How to extract alphanumeric word from column values in excel with Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need a way to extract all words that start with 'A' followed by a 6-digit numeric string right after (i.e. A112233, A000023).

Each cell contains sentences and there could potentially be a user error where they forget to put a space, so if you could account for that as well it would be greatly appreciated.

I've done research into using Python regex and Pandas, but I just don't know enough yet and am kind of on a time crunch.

[image: Excel Example]

Comment: Have you checked out the many examples on here? One, or more, of those could be edited to do what you need.

Comment: `extractall` is one way.  E.g., [Extract HTML information from df variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68764677/extract-html-information-from-df-variable/68765172#68765172).  Ignore that it's HTML in that question and follow the same process.  You just need to swap the regex to something like `(A\d{6})` or whatever works and alter the column(s) you're putting the extraction into depending on how many there are.  If you don't know how many are in the string dump to one column but add `.apply(', '.join)` to the end.

Comment: Okay I used your advice and got it to return all of the values. Is there an easy way to just get the values into a list without the column number?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your `df`'s content construct from the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "columnA":["A194533","A4A556633 system01A484666","A4A556633","a987654A948323a882332A484666","A238B004867","pageA000023lol","a089923","something lol a484876A48466 emoji","A906633 A556633a556633"]
        }
)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
                             columnA
0                            A194533
1          A4A556633 system01A484666
2                          A4A556633
3       a987654A948323a882332A484666
4                        A238B004867
5                     pageA000023lol
6                            a089923
7  something lol a484876A48466 emoji
8             A906633 A556633a556633
```

---

Now let's fetch the target corresponding to the regex patern:

```
result = df1['columnA'].str.extractall(r'([A]\d{6})')
```

Output:

```
               0
  match         
0 0      A194533
1 0      A556633
  1      A484666
2 0      A556633
3 0      A948323
  1      A484666
5 0      A000023
8 0      A906633
  1      A556633
```

And count them:

```
result.value_counts()
```

Output:

```
A556633    3
A484666    2
A000023    1
A194533    1
A906633    1
A948323    1
dtype: int64
```

Send the unique index into a list:

```
unique_list = [i[0] for i in result.value_counts().index.tolist()]
```

Output:

```
['A556633', 'A484666', 'A000023', 'A194533', 'A906633', 'A948323']
```

Value counts into a list:

```
unique_count_list = result.value_counts().values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: How can I get those values in a regular list? Thanks.

Comment: You wanna send uniqe A[6 digits] in to a list ?

Comment: Basically just take the output above and put the values on the left into a list if possible

Comment: Use **List Comprehension** and `index.tolist()` can make it work. Please check the further manipulation I added up.